# Modifying the maxspeed of a road from a large local OSM map

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium

I want to reduce the maxspeed value for the street Sainte-Hélène on a local osm map, too big to be open in JOSM:

I use the following steps:

```
# Filter highways and extract names                                                                                                                                                                         
osmium tags-filter map.osm.pbf nwr/highway --overwrite --output road_names.osm

# Convert OSM file to CSV                                                                                                                                                                                   
osmium export road_names.osm --output-format txt --output road_names.csv

# List unique road names                                                                                                                                                                                    
cut -d ' ' -f 3 road_names.txt | sort | uniq

# Extract the road segment you want to modify                                                                                                                                                               
osmium extract -p "name='Rue%20Sainte-Hélène'" map.osm.pbf -o road_segment.osm

# Edit the extracted OSM data to modify the speed limit tag (e.g., using a text editor)                                                                                                                     

# Apply changes back to the original PBF file                                                                                                                                                               
osmium merge road_segment.osm.pbf map.osm.pbf -o modified_map.osm.pb
```

But the extraction part is obviously wrong and I cannot find the argument to filter by name.

Comment: The `%20` is definitely wrong. Values in OSM tags are not URL-encoded. Simply try `name=Rue Sainte-Hélène` instead.

Comment: Right, I could then extract only the street. The merging however does not take into account the modification I brought on the extracted map.